# Запрет отправки формі Yii2

Tags: jquery

У меня есть форма. Хочу сделать запрет ее отправки, что бы переписать отправку на ajax. Пишу так:

```
$("#login_form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Но форма все равно отправляется. Вроде же верно код написал, что не так?

Comment: Может быть у вас еще один обработчик навешан. Попробуйте отключить его. `$("#login_form").off("submit").on("submit", function (e) {e.preventDefault()});`

Comment: не помогло, форма по прежнему отправляется

Comment: Дубликат ID? Форму саму находит? `$("#login_form")`, `$('[id="login_form"]')`. Может у вас ошибка в консоли есть? И обработчик просто не повесился. попробуйте добавить alert в функцию, ставлю на то что он не отобразится)

Comment: да, вы были правы. id повторялся еще раз, извините. спасибо за ответ. вынесите его как ответ

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#login_form").on("submit", function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           alert('Всё работает');
      });
      /*
      $('[id="login_form"]').on("submit", function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           alert('Костыль');
      });
      */
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="login_form">
 <input type="submit" name="Submit1" value="Нормально">
</form>
<form id="login_form">
 <input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="НеНормально">
</form>
```

Comment: я знаю, что там должно работать, но не работает. прошу учесть, что это yii2. модератор почему то сменил метку на jquery. может это yii2 как то влияет

Comment: Судя по тому кусочку кода что вы скинули. Никакого отношения к Yii2 невозможно провести. В консоли точно нет ошибок? Нужен тогда полный код страницы, чтоб более точно сказать что влияет.